# Как найти незанятые области через запрос MySql

Tags: mysql, select

Приложил картинку:
в базе хранятся закрашенные области (серый цвет), как координаты левого верхнего угла и правого нижнего, т.е. ЧЕТЫРЕ числа (х1,у1,х2,у2).
Как запросом в базу MySql получить координаты свободной области, если условия такие:

1. начиная сверху слева найти свободную область размером 1х1
2. начиная сверху слева найти свободную область размером 2х2

То есть для п.1 ответ должен быть 0,0,1,1 (голубой квадратик)
для п.2 = 6,0,8,2 (оранжевый квадратик)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Все, на что хватило знаний)) -это функцией MIN нахожу свободную координату по оси X, но в совокупности с осью Y это неправильно. И для поиска областей 2х2 поиск через MIN вообще не применим.
Как вариант, думал создать еще одну таблицу с перечислением всех возможных точек (т.е. для данного квадрата это 10х10=100 строк) и ставить пометку - такие-то точки заняты, а такие-то нет и искать среди незанятых, но если размер поля надо будет увеличить (с 10х10 до например 100х100), то скорее всего начнутся задержки???
База:

```html
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `m_items`;
CREATE TABLE `m_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `x1` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `y1` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `x2` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `y2` smallint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```html
INSERT INTO `m_items` (`id`, `x1`, `y1`, `x2`, `y2`) VALUES
(1, 3, 0, 6, 4),
(2, 8, 0, 9, 2),
(3, 0, 1, 2, 2),
(4, 0, 3, 2, 5),
(5, 7, 3, 9, 7),
(6, 1, 6, 6, 7),
(7, 1, 8, 2, 10);
```

Comment: Приведите образец тестовой таблицы с данными, заполенными на основании этой картинки, в формате, пригодном для прямой загрузки в БД. Т.е. SQL `create table` и `insert`'ы к нему

Comment: Уточните почему ответ для п2 не (6,0,7,1) ? Мы чтоли в поиске должны двигаться по оси Y, затем по X?

Comment: ОЙ ОШИБКА МОЯ!! действиетльно именно там будет второй овтет!! пропустил!! а так смысл найти все что подходит на верхней горизонтали слева направо, если нет, спускаемся ниже и также слева направо. обновил пост ссылкой на пациента

Comment: Все еще ищу алгоритм, варианты с поиском пересечений между двумя таблицами ввиду большого количества вариантов скорее всего не подойдут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
select x,y
from c -- см. ответ @mnv
left join m_items
on x <= X2-1 and
   x+2 >= X1 and
   y <= Y2-1 and
   y+2 >= Y1
where x+2<10 and y+2<10
and id is null
order by y, x;
```

+2 - это квадраты 3x3.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88faf/5)

Comment: ок, попробую.. спс

Comment: and id is null - айди какой таблицы? а то я поменял на разное написание в разных таблицах для упрощения экспериментов - для m_items не id  а m_id... если так то 2.0118 сек при поиске по сетке 1000х1000, т.е. таблица C содержит 1кк строк)) почему-то вывалило все результаты 16000 кубиков (всего 805000 строк)а не крайний от левого верхнего угла...

Comment: `id is null` можно заменить на `x1` или любое другое поле из `m_items`, это условие для "не найдено пересечений для квадрата с имеющимися прямоугольниками". Если вам нужен один, то добавьте limit 1. В ответе запрос выводит все свободные квадраты, да.

Comment: а неплохо прям! пока вроде как все правильно ищет... интересно, как вы так составили? конструктор какой? тут надо же визуально представить и соотнести с запросами... эксперимент показал что квадрат или прямоугольник без разницы, да? ну координаты соответственно ставить, т.е х+130 и у+340, да? единственно что не радует что запрос от 1,2 до 2,5 сек.. как тут можно побороть?

Comment: первая таблица 1млн строк и вторая 100 строк - поиск 2сек, а если во второй таблице 5000 строк, то поиск 372 сек!!... что же еще придумать-то?

Comment: условие - это условие пересечения многоугольников, а точнее пересечение отрезков (проекций на оси). да, можно искать не только квадраты. не знаю какая задача изначальная, методы оптимизации могут быть разные. кэширование, кластеризация (то, что @mnv предложил с разбиением на сегменты), хранение наоборот незанятых областей, вместо занятых... поскольку сравнение идет каждый с каждым, ускорить сам запрос вряд ли получится, надо менять алгоритм или сокращать объемы данных. ЗЫ индексы могут помочь (range все-таки лучше чем без индексов вовсе, например), но надо смотреть...

Comment: спасибо за то, что тратите время! хранить незанятые - это я тоже пробую, в одной таблице хранятся незанятые (помеченные полем статус), в другой занятые с полным перечнем еще и других параметров, тогда поиск незанятого просто как селект по первой таблице с поиском первого свободного статуса ну и ограничение на размеры, А вот как одновременно в первой таблице апдейтить что занято и во второй вставлять строку с непосредственно координатами и прочими если надо параметрами? Чтобы два пользователя не смогли выбрать одно и тоже?

Answer (score 6):

Можно сделать так. Строим табличку всех возможных комбинаций `x` и `y` (от 1 до 10). Чтобы проще воспринимался запрос для получения результата, оформляем это в виде временной таблицы:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS c AS (
    SELECT x, y FROM (
        SELECT 0 as x UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 
        UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) x
    CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 as y UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 
            UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
    ) y
);
```

В `@size` положим размер свободного квадрата. Тут 0 означает квадрат размером 1x1. Для квадрата 2x2 делаем так:

```
SET @size = 2 - 1;
```

Теперь все готово для того, чтобы найти ближайший свободный квадрат. Следующий запрос находит все свободные квадраты, сортирует результаты в нужном порядке и выбирает первый, что требуется по условию. Смысл запроса - поиск областей, которые не пересекаются с тем, что имеется на поле:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM t WHERE (
        (x >= x1 AND x <= x2) 
        OR (x + @size >= x1 AND x + @size <= x2)
        OR (x1 >= x AND x1 <= x + @size)
        OR (x2 >= x AND x2 <= x + @size)
    ) AND (
        (y >= y1 AND y <= y2) 
        OR (y + @size >= y1 AND y + @size <= y2)
        OR (y1 >= y AND y1 <= y + @size)
        OR (y2 >= y AND y2 <= y + @size)
    )
)
AND x < 10 - @size
AND y < 10 - @size
ORDER BY x, y
LIMIT 1;
```

Посмотреть пример и поэкспериментировать [можно тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3d9f6/2/1).

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**

Запрос выше для случая, когда надо двигаться сперва по оси y, потом по x (так изначально был поставлен вопрос). Если нужен ответ для отредактированного варианта вопроса, то просто поменяйте условие сортировки:

```
ORDER BY y, x
```

Comment: у вас  в примере 4 строки - линии а не прямоугольники...??

Comment: В примере на sqlfiddle в таблице t? Там прямоугольники. Каждая строка - один прямоугольник, который задается двумя точками {(x1, y1), (x2, y2)}.

Comment: @Сергей В. Еще обратил внимание, что вопрос немного скорректировали. Дописал к ответу как это реализовать.

Comment: да, спасибо! но это все-таки линия - 0, 1, 1, 1... и в итоге по-моему не то выдает что должно

Comment: Можно считать это и линией и прямоугольником, как вам удобнее. Вот иллюстрация этого фрагмента: http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1473537024.png. Я проверял результат на sqlfiddle, для вашего примера выдается корректный ответ - левая верхняя точка квадрата. Если в ответе нужна еще координата нижней правой точки, просто напишите в select вместо `*`: `x, y, x + @size, y + @size`.

Comment: почему-то у меня выходит x=3 y=8 - т.е. вообще где-то внизу. для моего набора исходных данных. а вот эта временная таблица - хорошо для 10х10, а если 100х100, она же разрастется неимоверно??? т.е. остается все-таки только вариант с созданием реальной второй таблицы с перечислением там всех вариантов??

Comment: Если у вас тот-же набор исходных данных, что в моем примере, то могу только предположить, что такой результат может получиться, если вы ищите место для квадрата 3x3 (`@size = 2`) и позиции в полученном результате нумеруете не с 0, а с 1. Для квадрата 100x100 во временной таблице будет всего 10000 записей. Это не много. Но производительность надо проверять на месте, затрудняюсь заранее оценить.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45208/discussion-between---and-mnv).

Comment: Время поиска по миллиону строк 4 сек, нужно чуть быстрее)))

Comment: @Сергей В. Если убрать `ORDER BY x, y`, поиск ускоряется?

Comment: Это ж главное - найти крайние слева сверху..Без ORDER смысл тогда??

Comment: @СергейВ. Я уточняю чтобы понять на что уходят ресурсы. Еще интересно сколько возвращается записей если убрать `LIMIT`.

Comment: без ORDER = 0.268сек. но результаты неправильные. с ORDER и без лимита выдает 389000 строк...

Comment: Это многовато для `ORDER BY`. Как вариант, можно разбивать поле на сегменты 100x100 с нахлестом в `@size` и искать ответы по очереди в каждом сегменте.

Comment: А если нужно сразу вставить строку в базу, записав при этом значения, соответствующие незанятым ячейкам, поиск не упростится?

Comment: Думаю что поиск ускорится для случаев, когда остается мало незанятых областей и замедлится для случаев когда незанятых областей много. Я на вашем месте попробовал бы просто в решении от @Yura Ivanov добавить составной индекс на y, x.