# Запрос в MySQL - найти числа вне интервалов

Tags: mysql, select, join

Пишу выборку и наверное торможу.
Первая таблица - набор от 1 до 1000, например
A=1
A=2
A=3
...
A=999
A=1000

Вторая таблица - набор пар значений, интервалы, например,
A=100 B=150
А=1 В=40
A=300 B=350

Сначала нарисовал поиск чисел из первой таблицы, которых нет во второй (т.е. по полю А) :

```
SELECT t1.a FROM table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on (t1.a=t2.a) WHERE t2.a IS NULL
```

Работает!
Теперь ищу числа из первой таблицы, которые не попадают в ИНТЕРВАЛЫ второй таблицы и тут встал... Еще один джойн что ли делать? А в итоге надо найти одно минимальное значение из выборки, т.е. в данном случае это 41.

Comment: Сравнивать нужно только левую границу A? Правая граница B вообще не участвует в запросе? Если речь об интервалах, вероятно должны работать обе границы? В этом случае ваш запрос не верен.

Comment: Ну да, мой запрос для поиска по А. А теперь хочу поправить запрос, чтобы включить в поиск и правую границу В

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```
select min(t1.a) a
from table1 t1 
  left join (select distinct tt1.a
    from table1 tt1
      join table2 tt2 on 
        tt1.a between tt2.a and tt2.b
  ) tt on t1.a=tt.a
where tt.a is null
```

Comment: tt - опечатка??

Comment: [нет](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb7be/3)

Comment: а, точно, соррян! Всё четко, спасибо! Вы по памяти собрали запрос или конструктор какой есть? Мне бы еще присоединить из второй таблицы еще одни интервалы, между C и D, т.е.как бы в двухмерной плоскости ))) Иначе говоря, во 2-1 таблице строка состоит из A B C D и интервалы между A B и  C D. В любом случае огромное спасибо!

Comment: вот похожее и там пока неудачно решили... http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564888/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-mysql

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы получить сначала значения **из** интервалов, а потом взять значение из дополнения.

Comment: собирал в редакторе, без конструктора.

Comment: эх, про скорость не спросил у вас. Сейчас забросил в базу, во второй таблице 1000000 строк, уже 10 минут ищет...(((

Comment: Есть ли индекс по `table1.a`? Можно убрать distinct попробовать (скорость может зависеть от разреженности интервалов). Я посмотрю первоначальную задачу (попозже), вполне возможно решение не оптимальное...

Comment: индексы сделал. так же долго. а по ABCD наверное еще дольше будет???