# Найти в MyISAM подряд идущие ячейки

Tags: mysql, select, myisam

Создана БД (MyISAM):
- id (от 0 до 10000, index)
- status (0 или 1)

Ищу первую с начала таблицы ячейку со статусом = 0:

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE status=0 ORDER by id ASC limit 1
```

ОК!

Ищу первые семь ячеек с начала таблицы со статусом = 0

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE status=0 ORDER by id ASC limit 7
```

ОК!

А как найти семь ячеек, которые идут подряд?

Comment: Вот в этом ответе вам же http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568258/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8E%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BC-mysql/568411#568411  первый запрос делает именно это

Comment: наверное да, хотел обойтись без подзапросов, но видимо нереально. странно, простая задача, если рисовать на листке и сложная в плане БД...

Comment: Но там внешний подзапрос просто преобразует данные полученные во внутреннем. это способ выразить то что нам надо, дополнительных обращений к таблицам же не происходит. Есть другие решения - но там только хуже, будет несколько обращений к таблице.

Comment: а как решить задачку в http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564888/Как-найти-незанятые-области-через-запрос-mysql, используя ваш метод, если в указанной задачке поменять исходные данные, а именно - ячейки сохранены в БД как в текущей задачке (каждая строка - это id + x + y + syatus)?

Comment: сначала собираем все строки подходящей длины, т.е. из внутреннего подзапроса получаем все записи с num=7 результат прогоняем через такой же цикл но уже считая у них совпадающие Y и берем минимальную запись уже с нужным количеством совпадения Y. В общем еще два этажа поверх этого запроса. надо будет попробовать на досуге. сейчас ухожу, как вернусь напишу вариант в тот вопрос. интересно, как оно выйдет, минут 5 назад мне казалось это невозможным ... :)

Comment: создал вопрос - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/570959/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-mysql