# Как найти первую подходящую область через запрос MySql

Tags: mysql, select, update

На картинке сетка 10х10=100 кубиков.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Создана БД, 100 строк, поля: id,x,y,s. Одна строка = один кубик.
x,y - координаты левого верхнего угла кубика.
Таким образом перечислены ВСЕ кубики, т.е.:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В БД хранятся закрашенные области (серый цвет), как несколько строк, у которых поле s=1. координаты левого верхнего угла, т.е. ДВА числа (х,у). Как запросом в базу MySql получить координаты свободной области (вернее, нужно проапдейтить статус с 0 на 1 у найденной области), если условия такие:

```
п.1 обходом слева направо и сверху вниз найти свободную область размером 1х1
п.2 обходом слева направо и сверху вниз найти свободную область размером 2х2
```

То есть для п.1 ответ должен быть - строка id=0 (голубой квадратик),
 для п.2 ответ - строки id=7, id=8, id=17, id=18 (оранжевый квадратик)
или касаемо п.2 так как заранее известны искомые ширина и высота, то достаточно получить id=7

**UPD**
спасибо решению от Mike, результат получается верный.
правда, время 2,23 сек...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: блин. жаль, хотел сделать себе удобную штуку для сбора и самое главное анализа статистики, видимо придется по старинке в екселе все делать....)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id записей неудобны для работы в данном случае поэтому запрос возвращает координаты верхнего левого и правого нижнего углов области:

```
select x-2+1 startX, y-2+1 startY, x endX, y endY
  from (
     select @num:=if(y=@y+1 and @x=x,@num+1,1) nY, @y:=y y, @x:=x x, nX
       from (
          select @num:=if(x=@x+1 and y=@y,@num+1,1) nX,@x:=x x, @y:=y y
            from table1 T, (select @x:=0, @num:=0, @y:=-1) A
           where status=0
           order by y, x
       ) B
  where nX>=2
  order by x, y
 ) C
 where nY>=2
 order by y, x
 limit 1
```

Подзапрос `B` последовательно нумерует все незанятые клетки лежащие в одной строке подряд. При пропуске клетки нумерация начинается с 1. Подзапрос `C` из этого получает все записи у которых номера больше необходимого размера области по X (фактически те клетки перед которыми есть достаточное количество свободных). При этом он нумерует идущие подряд в одной вертикали клетки. Внешний запрос отбирает из этого все области размеры которых равны или превышают указанный размер, а формулы в его начале отрезают от области кусок нужного размера.

Для обновления таблицы на основании этого запроса достаточно написать:

```
update table1 T
  join (наш запрос) N
    on T.x between N.startX and N.endX
   and T.y between N.startY and N.endY
   set status=1
```

Comment: йохохо, 4этажка? спасибо , сейчас пощупаю. а как это можно вставить в phpmyadmin? он ругается на переменные.

Comment: @СергейВ. Он что ли сам как то анализирует запрос ? там вроде был режим выполнения произвольного запроса. Я предпочитаю MySQL workbench он то все пропускает, правда он почему то у меня не показывает ошибки :) да и в нем "щупать" как раз проще, кусок внутренний выделили мышкой, он только его выполнит, можно посмотреть что вышло, представить что с этим дальше происходит

Comment: результат - через 2,3 сек......)) в PHPMyAdmin кстати подхватил этот вариант... Значит, индекс по id вообще не применяется? план запроса приложил в вопрос

Comment: @СергейВ. Ну да, последовательный перебор миллиона записей, да еще и трехкратная сортировка результатов (а результатов судя по всему то же под миллион, занятых то мест мало) будет медленной. А альтернативы этому при такой структуре БД гораздо хуже. И собственно чего же вы хотите, я с самого начала твержу, что таблица с отдельными местами и статусами ненужна. Нужны только занятые интервалы, как в том вопросе, на основе которого родился этот.

Comment: да там такое сложное дело, что получилось две крайности. могу подробнее написать на почту)) моя khp-volga на яндексе

Comment: @СергейВ. И собственно откуда у вас миллион записей то. это квадратное поле 1000x1000 что то я таких полей не видел. вы же вопросы начинали с того, что это какая то система резервирования. это где же у вас такая площадь с миллионом мест то

Comment: сейчас 3000, в плане на 2017 точно за 10к будет. тестирую на 1кк, чтобы выявить слабые места, т.к. то что в других темах решалось, на 3000 строк ну совсем мизерные цифры времени запроса получались, на 1кк уже видна разница. т.е. чтобы учесть многопоточность, а она будет, когда все-таки решу применить все это вживую, выкинув наконец-то телефон и ексель!)) я например не представляю, как проверить нагрузку бронирования, все сервисы дают просто заход на страницу, а тут некий набор действий - нажать, выбрать, забронировать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45977/discussion-between---and-mike).

Comment: а если для поиска например свободного КУБа 2х2 применить следующий алгоритм: находим все свободные клетки (у которых s=0, элементарно), далее ищем среди них те, которые под собой имеют также свободную клетку и справа свободную и вправо->вниз свободную, через сопоставление по id? Применительно к оранжевому КУБу надо проверить наличие среди свободных id=7, id=7+1, id=7+10, id=7+10+1 !!! Запрос должен получиться быстрый, знаний вот только маловато.

Comment: @СергейВ. КУБ - трехмерная фигура, если что. попробуйте. там простейший `select from T A where 3=(select count(1) from T where s=0 and T.id in(A.id+1,A.id+10,A.id+11))` И это решит только задачу 2x2.

Comment: за КУБ спасибо))) а почему решит только для 2х2? а больше чтобы искать - разве не достаточно просто еще добавить условий? по сути особо длинных увеличений и не надо, ну до 5х5 максимум. прямоугольники тоже нужны.

Comment: вот создал разжеванно http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571940/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-10%d1%8510

Comment: @СергейВ. Да что там создавать. Вы же практически написали то что надо. только exists ищет _хотя бы одну_ запись, А вам надо проверить наличие нескольких. Так что либо отдельный exists на каждый id, либо как я чуть выше написал, вместо слова exists пишите `3=` и внутри получаете count(1) т.е. кол-во подходящих записей

Comment: а что такое "3="  ??? первый раз такое вижу... РАВНО ТРЁМ?

Comment: @СергейВ. значит, что вот тот подзапрос который в скобках должен вернуть значение 3 (нам же надо убедится что все 3 клетки свободны) что бы условие выполнилось. по идее можно и наоборот `(select ...)=3`, просто в какой то БД цифра должна быть именно перед запросом и я не помню в какой именно и пишу всегда так на всякий случай.

Comment: в mySQL что-то ругается, я поправил select * from, а дальше как? T A - это две таблицы?

Comment: @СергейВ. T это таблица, а A это алиас. да вы свой запрос из того нового вопроса поправьте, что бы на 3 записи проверял и все. ну еще в подзапросе не забудьте указать status=0, а то вы сейчас любые записи находите